# How to login with multiple email addresses when using django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have a django project with the django-allauth app.
I want to authenticate by username or emailA or emailB.

I set ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD to username_email and
I confirmed that I can authenticate by username or email address.

Reading the documentation, it looks like I can use ACCOUNT_MAX_EMAIL_ADDRESSES,
but I don't know how to use it.

the documentation  django-allauth:

ACCOUNT_MAX_EMAIL_ADDRESSES(=None)
*The maximum amount of email addresses a user can associate to his account.
It is safe to change this setting for an already running project – it will not negatively affect users that already exceed the allowed amount.
Note that if you set the maximum to 1,
users will not be able to change their email address as they are unable to add the new address,
followed by removing the old address.*

I am new to django and am struggling with this.
Can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Mari and welcome to the wonderland of Django.

I worked with django-allauth but i didn't rember you can use several emails. Great.

First, let's say you want to allow users to associate up to 2 email addresses with their account. You can set this value in your settings.py file as follows:

```
ACCOUNT_MAX_EMAIL_ADDRESSES = 2
```

This will limit the number of email addresses that can be associated with a user account to 2.

Now, if you want to add a form field for users to enter an additional email address when registering or editing current one in their profile. You can use Django's built-in forms to create a custom form that includes an extra email field.
Here's an minimalist example of how to do this, i hope it will helps you:

```
from django import forms
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm, UserForm
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    email2 = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    def save(self, request):
        # call super save from parent class, here you have request because it come from a form sent by user
        user = super().save(request)
        
        # Associate the additional email address with the user's account
        if email2 := self.cleaned_data.get('email2'):
            EmailAddress.objects.create(user=user, email=email2, verified=True, primary=False)

        return user

class CustomUserForm(UserForm):
    email2 = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    def save(self):
        # call super save from parent class
        user = super().save()

        # Associate the additional email address with the user's account
        if email2 := self.cleaned_data.get('email2'):
            EmailAddress.objects.create(user=user, email=email2, verified=True, primary=False)

        return user
```

As you may be understood : use CustomSignupForm to your sign up page and CustomUserForm when you want edit user profile.
Note that i passed verified=True, because user is already registered but i think you have to revalidate this new email.
I put primary = False to add this email as a secondary one. But it's up to you.

Comment: Your answer is appropriate and my question has been answered.

I was trying my best to add the email to the coustam user model, but that was wrong.
I should have registered the email address in the account_emailaddress table to manage it!

Thank you very much.